# How to specify previous element's attribute in selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I have a JS selector:

```
"a[title*=Download]"
```

which will find link titled "Download". However, I would like it to match only when previous element's `id` attribute is for example "P24_MY_ID". How can I modify my first query? It should be one line selector.

UPDATE more code:

```
<input type="file" id="P24_MY_ID" name="p_t32" class="file"  size="30" />&nbsp;<a href="apex_util.get_blob_file?a=442&s=1281349283063&p=24&d=49830111238173502&i=163125708564179080&p_pk1=10980&p_pk2=&p_ck=67989B0EF83EF635B71455E04793731B&p_content_disposition=attachment" title="Download 1KB" alt="Download 1KB">Download</a>
```

Comment: can you please post more code so we are clear to answer you?

Comment: That's not a JS selector, it's a *CSS* selector. You may be using it in JavaScript, but that's not really relevant to your question.

Comment: @AkshayTilekar: updated with code.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks for editing.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: The right tag is [css-selectors]. This is a question about using CSS selectors in JavaScript, not a question about CSS. This distinction is important because workarounds for certain limitations may exist in a CSS context such as overriding rules and declarations that don't apply in a scripting environment (and vice versa).

Comment: @BoltClock: Fair point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [*adjacent sibling combinator*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), `+`:

```css
#P24_MY_ID + a[title*=Download]
```

That selects the one `a[title*=Download]` element that *directly follows* the one `#P24_MY_ID` element (as IDs have to be unique).

Live example with your sample HTML:

```js
var link = document.querySelector("#P24_MY_ID + a[title*=Download]");
link.style.color = "red";
console.log("Total matching: ", document.querySelectorAll("#P24_MY_ID + a[title*=Download]").length);
```

```html
Matches this link only (turning it red):
<br><input type="file" id="P24_MY_ID" name="p_t32" class="file"  size="30" />&nbsp;<a href="apex_util.get_blob_file?a=442&s=1281349283063&p=24&d=49830111238173502&i=163125708564179080&p_pk1=10980&p_pk2=&p_ck=67989B0EF83EF635B71455E04793731B&p_content_disposition=attachment" title="Download 1KB" alt="Download 1KB">Download</a>
<hr>
And not for instance this one:
<br><a href="apex_util.get_blob_file?a=442&s=1281349283063&p=24&d=49830111238173502&i=163125708564179080&p_pk1=10980&p_pk2=&p_ck=67989B0EF83EF635B71455E04793731B&p_content_disposition=attachment" title="Download 1KB" alt="Download 1KB">Download</a>
```